# javac and scalac warnings as errors only for certain types

Tags: java, scala, warnings

I know that with -Werror and -Xfatal-warnings I can make warnings as errors, but is it possible to still see all warnings in the compilation output, but only make a few of them become errors?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, with `scalac` alone.

You could perhaps add a post-build check to your build scripts which grep the output for warnings about your critical classes and fail the build if any are found?